# When updating the ParentRecordId lookup field in a PartnerNetworkRecordConnection, is it normal for ParentRecordId not to update on the other org?

Tags: lookup, salesforce2salesforce

In my Salesforce to Salesforce connection, each time a case is inserted and/or updated in my source org X, a `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` is created (`after insert` and `after update`) to forward the case from source org X to target org Y. When the case is inserted into source org X, the `AccountID` lookup field that I have specified in the field `ParentRecordId` of the `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` object will be correctly inserted in the case that was exported to target org Y.

However, if I update target org Y's `AccountID` lookup field that was mapped to `ParentRecordId`, the update will not be made to the corresponding lookup field in source org X.

Why is this?

---

My first guess is that `PartnerNetworkRecordConnections` do not support updates of `ParentRecordId` lookup fields, and if so, what is the solution to be able to update `ParentRecordId` lookup fields in one org, and for it to automatically update in the other?

---

The method that is called `after insert` and `after update` is as so:

```
 //PO autoforward to Contact
public static void autoforwardAggregatorCase(List<Case> caseList) {
    List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection> conAggregatorInsertList = new List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection>();
    S2S_Connection__c s2sAG = S2S_Connection__c.getValues('Connection');
    for(Case cse : caseList) {
        if(!AccountHelper.hasAlreadyCreatedAggregatorS2S()) {
            if(cse.RecordTypeId == Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Equipment Record').getRecordTypeId() && cse.Status != 'Draft' && cse.IsClosed == false) {
                PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newConnection =
                new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection(
                    ConnectionId = s2sAG.connection_id__c, // custom settings
                    LocalRecordId = cse.Id,
                    SendClosedTasks = false,
                    SendOpenTasks = false,
                    SendEmails = false,
                    ParentRecordId = cse.AccountId,
                    RelatedRecords = 'Capability__c,Attachment,CaseComment');
                conAggregatorInsertList.add(newConnection);
            }
        }
    }
    if(conAggregatorInsertList.size() > 0) {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            try {
                insert conAggregatorInsertList;
                AccountHelper.setAlreadyCreatedAggregatorS2S();
            } catch (DmlException e) {      if(e.getMessage().contains('INVALID_PARTNER_NETWORK_STATUS')) {
                    if(e.getMessage().contains('invalid status for partner network operation'))
                        caseList.get(0).addError('Record Sharing Error. Unable to share Case. Organisation is not currently shared.');
                    else
                        caseList.get(0).addError('Record Sharing Error. There are no valid Customer Connect connections.');
                }

            }                       
        }
    }        
}
```